# How can I align this menu to be center?

Tags: html, css

I have this site:

[link](http://dg-design.ch/bagel/)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="content-menu">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
            <div class="logo-mobile">
                <a href="#"><img src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/logo-mobile.png"></a>
                <ul class="lang-top navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">En</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">fr</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
            <div class="menu-menu-1-container">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menu-menu-1">
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-22" id="menu-item-22">
                        <a href="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/?page_id=4" title="Home">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-27" id="menu-item-27">
                        <a href="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/?page_id=10" title="News">News</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-65" id="menu-item-65">
                        <a href="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/?page_id=63" title="Events">Events</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-71" id="menu-item-71">
                        <a href="http://www.smood.ch/en/156_bagel-house-caf%C3%A9" target="_blank" title="Delivery">Delivery</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-23" id="menu-item-23">
                        <a href="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/?page_id=6" title="About us">About us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25" id="menu-item-25">
                        <a href="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/?page_id=12" title="Contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <ul class="lang-top navbar-right">
                <li><img src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/logo-menu.png"></li>
                <li class="icon"><img src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/menu.png"></li>
                <li class="icon">
                    <a href="#">MENU</a>
                </li>
                <li class="icon">
                    <a href="#">En</a>
                </li>
                <li class="icon">
                    <a href="#">fr</a>
                </li>
                <li class="icon"><img src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/menu.png"></li>
                <li class="icon"><img src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/menu.png"></li>
                <li class="icon"><img src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/menu.png"></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
.wrapper .content .content-menu {
  /* width: 91%; */
  /*background: #5B626A;*/
  position: absolute;
  z-index:9999;
  /* left: 4%; */
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

I tried to put the above code `"text align: center"` but unfortunately does not work. Can you tell me please why it does not work?

What must I change for the items to be aligned in the center on any resolution?

[image]

Comment: I see the menu centered in the link you attach. What's the real problem?

Comment: I added a picture to understand more clearly what the problem

Comment: I hope you added a hyphen in "text align: center" .It should be `text-align:center;`

Comment: I added but still does not work ... you tried you work?

Comment: You need to post a fully working html/css code piece

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

put the ul into the div

```
        <div class="menu-menu-1-container">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menu-menu-1">
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-22" id="menu-item-22">
                    <a href="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/?page_id=4" title="Home">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-27" id="menu-item-27">
                    <a href="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/?page_id=10" title="News">News</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-65" id="menu-item-65">
                    <a href="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/?page_id=63" title="Events">Events</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-71" id="menu-item-71">
                    <a href="http://www.smood.ch/en/156_bagel-house-caf%C3%A9" target="_blank" title="Delivery">Delivery</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-23" id="menu-item-23">
                    <a href="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/?page_id=6" title="About us">About us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25" id="menu-item-25">
                    <a href="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/?page_id=12" title="Contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

           <ul class="lang-top navbar-right">
            <li><img src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/logo-menu.png"></li>
            <li class="icon"><img src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/menu.png"></li>
            <li class="icon">
                <a href="#">MENU</a>
            </li>
            <li class="icon">
                <a href="#">En</a>
            </li>
            <li class="icon">
                <a href="#">fr</a>
            </li>
            <li class="icon"><img src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/menu.png"></li>
            <li class="icon"><img src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/menu.png"></li>
            <li class="icon"><img src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/menu.png"></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

in css:

```
#menu-menu-1, .lang-top{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

remote float: left from both the ul

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav {
 padding-left: 17px;
 padding-top: 75px;
 padding-bottom: 75px;
}

#menu-menu-1-container{
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

This the result:

[image: result]

Comment: and how to change it? so I resorted to this post :)

Comment: Let me investigate :)

Comment: @Marius I changed my answer: I put both the ul into the div container #menu-menu-1-container, then in the container put text-align: center and position:relative, while in the two ul put display: inline-block

Comment: @Marius no width is necessary now

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
        <div class="menu-menu-1-container">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menu-menu-1"></ul>
            <ul class="lang-top navbar-right"></ul>
        </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse{
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 1500px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: not figure out what changes you made to the html ... remained the same?

Comment: @Marius,  I added CSS to the  `collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse` and I pulled in your second list `ul` inside the first div `menu-menu-1-container`.

Answer (score 0):

Create one More Div under navbar tag fixed width & set the nav css according width class ex : -

```
<div class="content-menu">
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
    <div class="width">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
        <div class="logo-mobile">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/logo-mobile.png"></a>
            <ul class="lang-top navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">En</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">fr</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
        <div class="menu-menu-1-container">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menu-menu-1">
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-22" id="menu-item-22">
                    <a href="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/?page_id=4" title="Home">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-27" id="menu-item-27">
                    <a href="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/?page_id=10" title="News">News</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-65" id="menu-item-65">
                    <a href="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/?page_id=63" title="Events">Events</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-71" id="menu-item-71">
                    <a href="http://www.smood.ch/en/156_bagel-house-caf%C3%A9" target="_blank" title="Delivery">Delivery</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-23" id="menu-item-23">
                    <a href="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/?page_id=6" title="About us">About us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25" id="menu-item-25">
                    <a href="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/?page_id=12" title="Contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <ul class="lang-top navbar-right">
            <li><img src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/logo-menu.png"></li>
            <li class="icon"><img src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/menu.png"></li>
            <li class="icon">
                <a href="#">MENU</a>
            </li>
            <li class="icon">
                <a href="#">En</a>
            </li>
            <li class="icon">
                <a href="#">fr</a>
            </li>
            <li class="icon"><img src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/menu.png"></li>
            <li class="icon"><img src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/menu.png"></li>
            <li class="icon"><img src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/menu.png"></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.width{ width:1100px; margin:auto; }
```

width set on your screen size max screen size is 1100px / 1050px laptop - computer

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) Open a div tag between wrapper and container.
Step 2) Add css code to style tag.

HTML:

```
<div class="warpper" >
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="container ">
         YOUR MENU BLOCK
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.middle {
width: 75%;
position: absolute;
margin-left: -37%;
left: 50%;
}
```